# what are other ways of 301 links. Is there any plugin for doing it in symfony..?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony1, http-status-code-301, response.redirect

I am using symfony 1.0.6 and I need to 301 many links (52 links).
The only way I know is using .htaccess redirection.

Is there any plugin which can do this job ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have only worked with symfony 1.4 but maybe it also works in symfony 1.0.x:

Maybe you could modify your routing settings and create a module with action "executeRedirect301" which headers a 301 - and route all actions you want to this route.

You also could set the default route to the "executeRedirect301" action and only create/keep those routes you want to left over.